# Formatting output in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am sending a query result to multiple mails for managerial seek.

The output is not well organized

[out put in the mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll4tt.png)

I want the output to be more organized and in a better order than it is now.

How can I do it?

PS: I tried to use 'cast' but out put remains the same

Comment: What ***exactly*** show the "better" output look like?? "Better" is always very much subjective - what are you trying to do, *exactly*?

Comment: columns be aligned

Comment: Is the email text or html? You could try adding html markup

Comment: email text not html

Comment: So is the text shown in a fixed width font? If you don't know or don't have any control over it (which is true - you don't know what client it will be read in), then there is no way to align columns.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is a data Management system, you cannot rely on sql server to present data as well, for data presentation you should make use of a proper tool, some sort of reporting tool like SSRS, QlikView or tableau etc.

Anyway you can create some html on the fly from your sql server query and use that HTML in your email Body.

### Test Data

```
Declare @t table (Asset_Name VARCHAR(100), Expire_Date DATE)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Fortigate100D'  , '2016-09-01'),
('Test'           , '2016-09-15')
```

### Query

```
Declare @htmlBody nvarchar(max); 

SET @htmlBody = N'<table border="1">  
                <tr>
                    <th>Asset_Name</th>
                    <th>Expire_Date</th>
                </tr>'

SELECT @htmlBody + CAST ( (
SELECT td = CAST(ISNULL(Asset_Name,'') AS VARCHAR(100)),'',
       td = ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,Expire_Date,120),''),''
FROM @t 
ORDER BY Asset_Name
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) + '</table>'


PRINT @htmlBody
```

### Result

The html table will be create and in the browser it would look like....

```html
<table border="1"> 
 <tr>
  <th>Asset_Name</th>
  <th>Expire_Date</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Fortigate100D</td>
  <td>2016-09-01</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>2016-09-15</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: okkk thxxxx a loooot